# Terraform SQL create users from variable

Tags: mysql, terraform, multiple-users

I have users defined in  tfvars:

```
test_database_users = ["td" , "tdus", "tdbusrs"]
```

Resource is defined as:

```
resource "template_dir" "test_db_users" {
  ...
    vars {
         db_tusers = ${element(var.test_database_users, count.index)}"
         }
}
```

Trying to create a SQL command to create each database user which does not work:

```
CREATE USER ${element(db_tusers, 0)} FOR LOGON ${element(db_tusers, 0)};
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','${element(db_tusers, 0)}'
GO
```

I'm struggling with the proper syntax to bring each user into the create user command.

Comment: This may be a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as it's infrastructure related.

Answer (score 2):

It is often more straightforward to make Terraform work for the single case, then use the `count` parameter to expand it to > 1 cases.

As the docs [mention](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#template-syntax), you cannot access interpolation functions inside of the template, you need to pass them through the `variables` resouce in `template_dir`.

> To access interpolations that are normally available to Terraform configuration (such as other variables, resource attributes, module outputs, etc.) you'll have to expose them via vars [...]

For a single `database_user`, we pass the `database_user` as into the `template_dir` to use as `${user}`

`sql_templates/create_user.sql`

```
CREATE USER ${user} FOR LOGON ${user};
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','${user}'
GO
```

`main.tf`

```
variable "database_user" {
  default = "td"
}

resource "template_dir" "config" {
  source_dir      = "sql_templates"
  destination_dir = "sql_scripts"

  vars = {
    user = "${var.database_user}"
  }
}
```

This creates the expected output

```
.
├── main.tf
├── sql_scripts
│   └── create_user.sql
└── sql_templates
    └── create_user.sql
```

To expand this to multiple `database_users`, you can make use of `count` inside the
`template_dir` resource.

`main.tf`

```
variable "database_users" {
  default = ["td", "tdus", "tdbusrs"]
}

resource "template_dir" "config" {
  source_dir      = "sql_templates"
  destination_dir = "sql_scripts/${var.database_users[count.index]}/"
  count           = "${length(var.database_users)}"

  vars = {
    user = "${element(var.database_users, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

**Note:** The use of `${var.database_users[count.index]}` inside
`desination_dir` prevents terraform from using the same destination for all the
rendered outputs, and instead creates a new subfolder for each user

```
.
├── main.tf
├── sql_scripts
│   ├── td
│   │   └── create_user.sql
│   ├── tdbusrs
│   │   └── create_user.sql
│   └── tdus
│       └── create_user.sql
└── sql_templates
    └── create_user.sql
```